# PHP automatically do something 48 hours before a certain date

Tags: php, cron

I'm using [Phalcon 3.4](https://phalcon.io/en-us) with PHP 7.2 and MySQL 4.7.3.

So in my Database I store dates `(start_date and end_date)` and I need to do something (send a mail to a customer) 48 hours before the `start_date`. I need to do that just once.

I think the only way to do that is to use cron job ?

I see only one solution for that . My solution is to create a cron job who call my web service every hour and inside my web service I gonna check if there is 1 or more `start_date` < to 48 hours compared from now. Then I get all related customers and I send an email for each customer.

I'm posting a question here because I'm not sure if it's very good to create an hourly cron job for that. I'd like to know if you know other solutions to do that. Maybe there is another technology ?

Comment: Your approach is totally correct.

Comment: That is how I would do it. Obviously you need to mark the records as having been sent so that you don't send 48 emails.

Comment: Ok thank you guys to confirm. I was really not sure if my approach was good but ok it's cool :) I don't know how to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a perfect fit for `cron` indeed.

Possible pitfalls:

- if the task takes longer than the interval (i.e. runs over 1 hr in your case), cron will happily run another one; if the processing gets long, you might want to check for that
- cron won't run a missed task (e.g. if your task is scheduled at 2:30 and a DST change happens, it will skip and only run the next one) - that is already handled in your case by the "less than" check.
- you may wish to set some sort of flag "this is currently processed" and then "this was processed successfully", so that e.g. a manual invocation doesn't process the same task while a cron is running
- cron doesn't check that the task finished successfully, you may wish to check this directly in your main code, or run another "cleanup" cron service periodically
- note also the timezones, where applicable (e.g. if all your date operations run in UTC, this is mostly a non-issue)

Comment: One thing you can use to prevent multiple invocations of the same process (if the first runs too long) is [flock](https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock).

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. I'm thinking to another thing. Do you think that Queuing Messaging can do that too ?

Comment: @Unimportant: Sure, there are many ways of doing that. In a similar task, I prefer updating the database row with `date_started`, `machine_node_id`, `process_id`, and eventually `date_finished`, if it does finish - that way, it is possible to query which machine took the task, how long it ran (or if it's still running, or perhaps hangs), etc.

Comment: I like messaging systems, but for this case, I don't see a good fit. Those would be far better for asynchronous processing where you don't know exactly when it would be needed and how often, e.g. "if a file is uploaded then run processing on it". You could make it work *with* cron, e.g. "cron triggers a check event, check event triggers asynchronous client processing event(s) as applicable", but that seems overengineered here. Perhaps for version 2? ;)

Comment: @Piskvor Ok I see. So with Beanstalk it's impossible to send a job and tell to the tube "You gonna execute this job at this date" ?

Comment: No idea about Beanstalk specifically, TBH. Generally, messaging systems don't handle scheduling, as that's a completely different problem domain. I can imagine a scheduling system waking up periodically, checking, and *then* sending message(s) "someone execute this job now" to Beanstalk.